# How to uninstall MS .NET Core 1.0 RC2 VS 2015 Tooling Preview 1 without the installer?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

Several weeks ago I installed

> Microsoft .NET Core 1.0 RC2 Visual Studio 2015 Tooling Preview 1

But several days ago  a newer version was released so I have to uninstall the current one before installing the newer one.

When I click the `Uninstall` on the following dialog box,

[image]

the uninstaller prompts me to provide the installer. Unfortunately, the installer has been removed and I don't know where I can find it again.

## Question

I think that prompting us to provide the installer to proceed the un-installation might be a very bad idea. By the way, how to uninstall  MS .NET Core 1.0 RC2 VS 2015 Tooling Preview 1 without the installer?

Comment: Have you find a way to do it?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

I downloaded the exe from link below, then pointed to it when promted, worked great!

http://download.microsoft.com/download/4/6/1/46116DFF-29F9-4FF8-94BF-F9BE05BE263B/DotNetCore.1.0.0.RC2-VS2015Tools.Preview1.exe

Comment: Does anyone have an other link to this version? This one is offline sadly 